# Parasympathetic dominance in a state of alertness and elevated resistance?

Tags: stress

According to various sources

The parasympathetic nervous system remains dominant in the resistance stage of the general adaptation syndrome

> The body resists and compensates as the parasympathetic nervous system attempts to return many physiological functions to normal levels while body focuses resources against the stressor and remains on alert.

Source: https://mhcc.pressbooks.pub/hpe295/chapter/general-adaptation-syndrome/

> The resistance stage is governed by a part of the ANS called the parasympathetic.

The parasympathetic branch of the ANS tries to return the body to normal by reducing the amount of cortisol produced. The heart rate and blood pressure begin to return to normal.

Source: https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/320172

But other sources state that digestion is inhibited in the resistance stage

Source:https://courses.ecampus.oregonstate.edu/hhs231/seven/studyguide.htm

My question is, why is the parasympathetic nervous system dominant in the resistance stage of the GAS model when there is a state of alertness and a sustained release of cortisol?